# merge four different queries in one

Tags: mysql

Let's assume I have these four queries:

```
SELECT id_cre as credito, 
    data_eff as data, 
    '0.00' as incasso, 
    importo_fatt as spesa 
from fatture 
WHERE data_eff < '2014-12-31' 
UNION
SELECT id_cre as credito, 
    data_prev as data, 
    '0.00' as incasso, 
    importo_fatt as spesa 
from fatture 
WHERE data_prev >= '2014-12-31' 
UNION 
SELECT id_cre as credito, 
    data_prev as data, 
    importo as incasso, 
    '0.00' as spesa 
from incassi_prev 
WHERE data_prev >= '2014-12-31' 
UNION 
SELECT id_cre as credito, 
    data_inc as data, 
    importo_inc as incasso, 
    '0.00' as spesa 
from incassi_row 
WHERE data_inc < '2014-12-31'
```

I use them to extract a code (credito) a date (data) and an amount of money) that can be an income (incasso) or an expense (spesa).

The result can create duplicated rows (rows with the same code but once with an income and another with an expense). How can I rewrite the query to put on the same line income and expenses that have the same code and date? I'd like to do it with mysql because I already need to loop through the resulting array in javascript to rewrite the table by rows (each code as a row and each month as a column).

Furthermore, is there any way to do the same but considering the same date two different dates in the same month/year (eg. `2014-12-20` and `2014-12-31`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT credito, data, SUM(incasso) AS incasso, SUM(speca) AS speca
  FROM
(
  SELECT id_cre AS credito, data_eff AS data, 0.0 AS incasso, importo_fatt AS spesa 
    FROM fatture 
   WHERE data_eff < '2014-12-31' 
   UNION
  SELECT id_cre AS credito, data_prev AS data, 0.0 AS incasso, importo_fatt AS spesa 
    FROM fatture 
   WHERE data_prev >= '2014-12-31' 
   UNION 
  SELECT id_cre AS credito, data_prev AS data, importo AS incasso, 0.0 AS spesa 
    FROM incassi_prev 
   WHERE data_prev >= '2014-12-31' 
   UNION 
  SELECT id_cre AS credito, data_inc AS data, importo_inc AS incasso, 0.0 AS spesa 
    FROM incassi_row 
   WHERE data_inc < '2014-12-31'
) q
GROUP BY credito, data
```

Comment: it works! I tried doing group only on credito and not also on data. Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there a way to merge all dates of the same month in this query?